# Is it correct to use the preposition "of" in "the possibility of correcting the flatness of"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to use of preposition "of" in my sentence?

> The metallic transport skeleton has the possibility **of** correcting the flatness **of** the working surface according to the slope of the floor.

Please mention another option to deliver the same idea in this sentence.

Comment: *of* is fine.  The possibility is a quality that belongs to the correcting, and the flatness is a quality that belongs to the surface.  I'm not sure why you would want to use a different option.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition *of* is fine. I suggest to use **ability** rather than *possibility* if the working mechanism of the skeleton has been proven.

We could consider the changes as shown below.

> The metallic transport skeleton has the **ability** of **adjusting/levelling** the working surface according to the slope of the floor.

> The metallic transport skeleton has the **ability** to **adjust/level** the working surface according to the slope of the floor.

Comment: What about replacing "has the ability to" with "can"? Simpler style, easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.